# Upload a JSON from a third party application

Tags: 7, services

I have a client hosted on Acquia, and they are requesting that we implement functionality to allow another companies 3rd party application to upload a JSON file to an upload directory within their Drupal 7 website, or alternatively POST json data to the Drupal 7 website and we save that as a json file on the Drupal 7 upload directory.

Is this possible with Drupal 7? Services? Post request with ftp credentials?

Note: As clarified in the comments I would much prefer if the third party could create a service which serves the JSON data which we can just consume via feeds. But it doesn't seem like thats an option from their end, they have the ability to send post requests with data. This JSON data will not be converted into nodes, it will simply be consumed by another third party application hosted on a Drupal page which creates the display/layout for the JSON data which should be dynamically updated daily. The JSON data is public, but the request for JSON should be authenticated.

Comment: Would advise doing a POST with credentials to an endpoint, then handling that response in Drupal in a custom module. No FTP.

Comment: The answer is yes. But then it's a too broad question.

Comment: We don't want to use FTP anyway going to be a pain in the ass with Acquia, kinda defeats the purpose of Acquia's security anyway. I've never worked with services in Drupal 7 before, just wondering if this is possible with Drupal, i'm having a difficult time finding relevant examples or documentation of similar functionality

Comment: Could this be dealt with as a pull rather than a push?  You could them possibly use the Cron system to safely information from the 3rd party on a regular basis.  IMHO, much safer since you control the URL / access info outside of Drupal and the public inet.  Alternatively would be to use Drupal feeds which can read JSon info and parse it into Drupal nodes.  But not sure this would meet your json file needs like the cron process could.

Comment: @CGMonroe I would much prefer if the third party could create a service which serves the JSON data which we can just consume via feeds. But it doesn't seem like thats an option from their end, they have the ability to send post requests with data. This JSON data will not be converted into nodes, it will simply be consumed by another third party application hosted on a Drupal page which creates the display/layout for the JSON data which should be dynamically updated daily. The JSON data is public, but the request for JSON should be authenticated.